# Button in push notification in iOS not appear (swift)

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add a action button for my push notifications, but the button its not in my push, this is the code im using to add the button in my app delegate, the dismissAction2 one i tried too and its not working, what can i do?

```
let dismissAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss", title: "Dismiss", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)

let dismissAction2 = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss",
                                                              title: "Dismsiss",
                                                              options:.authenticationRequired, textInputButtonTitle: "Button", textInputPlaceholder: "")

let dismissCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "dismissCategory",
                                                         actions: [dismissAction],
                                                         intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                         options: [])

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([dismissCategory])
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
```